# Firebase Function Fails to deploy because of Dependency

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to write a Cloud function in nodejs that downloads images in google cloud storage then compiles them into a short video with the library [Editly][1]. Whenever I try to deploy the function I get the following error

```js
Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=18.16.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: python: not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'python commit_id.py check ..' returned exit status 127 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/workspace/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-22-cloud-amd64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/layers/google.nodejs.runtime/node/bin/node" "/workspace/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-06-12T18_15_16_459Z-debug-0.log. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-central1/9901c171-df82-40f3-9038-9f5c35417bc9?project=694499372205.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        videocreation:createVideo(us-central1)
```

Here is the function in index.js:

```js
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

const path = require("path");
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

initializeApp();

exports.createVideo = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const imagesBucket = await getStorage().bucket().getFiles();
  const images = await Promise.all(
    imagesBucket[0].map(async (image) => {
      await image.download({ destination: path.join(__dirname, image.id) });
      return path.join(__dirname, image.id);
    })
  );
  const Editly = await import("editly");
  await Editly({
    outPath: path.join(__dirname, "out.mp4"),
    audioFilePath: path.join(
      __dirname,
      "Sheck%20Wes%20-%20Mo%20Bamba%20(Lyrics).mp3"
    ),
    fps: 30,
    width: 1080,
    loopAudio: true,
    clips: images
      .filter((pathToImage) => !pathToImage.includes(".mp3"))
      .map((imagePath) => {
        return {
          duration: 3,

          layers: [
            {
              type: "image",
              path: imagePath,
            },
          ],
        };
      }),
  });
});
```

Here is the package.json

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "lintfix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "editly": "^0.14.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/fabric": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
[1]: https://github.com/mifi/editly

Comment: Have you checked if `node-gyp` is installed by following this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp)?

Comment: When I run it locally(modified a bit to run as a script), it works. Would this still cause an issue? Either way I tried installing it again and no luck